# Connection between erlang to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, erlang

I need one small program that connect database from erlang. Please help me to get connect between two. I want start develop some product using erlang so i need how erlang should be connected to mongodb?

Answer (score 1):

there is no official erlang driver for mongo
you can use third party drivers

- https://github.com/comtihon/mongodb-erlang
- https://github.com/SergejJurecko/erlmongo

Comment: Can we host erlang program independently?

Comment: Yes, you can connect to any DB on any host